# CompactDecimal Format for same Locales differs on device

Tags: android, locale

Using CompactDecimalFormat to format numbers. My code is-

```
public static String getCompactForm(double number) {

    if(number<1000) return "";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        CompactDecimalFormat numberFormat = CompactDecimalFormat
                .getInstance(getLocale(),CompactDecimalFormat.CompactStyle.SHORT);

        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        return numberFormat.format(number);
    }

    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

    if (number < 1000000) return numberFormat.format(number / 1000) + "K";
    else if (number < 1000000000) return numberFormat.format(number / 1000000) + "M";
    else  return numberFormat.format(number / 1000000000) + "B";

}
```

```
public static Locale getLocale(){
      //  return new Locale("en","IN");
        Locale locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
        }else locale=Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;

        String language=locale.getLanguage();
        String country=locale.getCountry();

        if(country.length()!=0 && language.length()!=0) return locale;
        if(language.length()==0 && country.length()==0) return new Locale("en","US");
        else if(language.length()==0) return new Locale("en",country);
        else return new Locale(language,"US");

    }
```

Code is working fine but for locale- en_IN expected result for input 1000000 should be 10L but getting 1M. Similar reults are genereted for thousands billion also.
I'm testing results on device with version above N.

Not able to figure out issue. Any help is much appreciated.